# How to splitting words match by patterns with PHP

Tags: php

I have an array of words. e.g.,

`$pattern = ['in', 'do', 'mie', 'indo'];`

I wanna split a words match by the patterns to some ways.

**input** =

```
indomie
```

to **output** =

```
$ in, do, mie
$ indo, mie
```

any suggests?

*ps sorry for bad english. thank you very much!

Comment: use preg_replace

Comment: Why does `mie` appear in both lists?

Comment: the output mean the input can be splitted into some ways but still matched with the pattern

Comment: why do you have two output ?  if you input indomie i think the output will be equal to in, do, mie, indo ... am i right ?

Comment: @V.Prince because "indomie" can splitted to 2 ways. match with the pattern

Comment: Just to understand your question properly: the input "indomo" would not be split at all, because the last syllable "mo" is not listed in the pattern array? And what would happen with "indodo" where the same syllable occurs twice?

Comment: yes of course @cars10m

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff omg, thank you very much dude, i just wanna re-post the question and attach my code, last night my mind just blown up so i forgot to attach the code. Thank you very much and have a nice day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was an very interesting question.

**Input:-**

> $inputSting  = "indomie";
>
> $pattern = ['in', 'do', 'mie', 'indo','dom','ie','indomi','e'];

**Output:-**

> in,do,mie
>
> in,dom,ie
>
> indo,mie
>
> indomi,e

Approach to this challenge

1. Get the pattern string length
2. Get the all the possible combination of matrix
3. Check whether the pattern matching.

if i understand your question correctly then above @V. Prince answer will work only for finding max two pattern.

```
    function sampling($chars, $size, $combinations = array()) {

        if (empty($combinations)) {
            $combinations = $chars;
        }

        if ($size == 1) {
            return $combinations;
        }

        $new_combinations = array();

        foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
            foreach ($chars as $char) {
                $new_combinations[] = $combination . $char;
            }
        }

        return sampling($chars, $size - 1, $new_combinations);
    }



    function splitbyPattern($inputSting, $pattern)
    {

        $patternLength= array();
        // Get the each pattern string Length
        foreach ($pattern as $length) {

            if (!in_array(strlen($length), $patternLength))
            {
                array_push($patternLength,strlen($length));
            }

        }
        // Get all the matrix combination of pattern string length to check the probablbe match
        $combination = sampling($patternLength, count($patternLength));
        $MatchOutput=Array();

        foreach ($combination as $comp) {
            $intlen=0;
            $MatchNotfound = true;
            $value="";

            // Loop Through the each probable combination
            foreach (str_split($comp,1) as $length) {
                 if($intlen<=strlen($inputSting))
                 {
                     // Check whether the pattern existing
                     if(in_array(substr($inputSting,$intlen,$length),$pattern))
                    {
                        $value = $value.substr($inputSting,$intlen,$length).',';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $MatchNotfound = false;
                        break;
                    }
                 }
                 else
                 {           
                    break;
                 }

                $intlen = $intlen+$length;
            }       
            if($MatchNotfound)
            {
                array_push($MatchOutput,substr($value,0,strlen($value)-1)); 
            }
        }

        return array_unique($MatchOutput);
    }

 $inputSting  = "indomie";

    $pattern = ['in', 'do', 'mie', 'indo','dom','ie','indomi','e'];

    $output = splitbyPattern($inputSting,$pattern);

    foreach($output  as $out)
    {
        echo $out."<br>";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: mine only works in a sorted pattern.. and by the way the max output depends on pattern count...

Answer (score 1):

try this one..
and if this solves your concern. try to understand it.
Goodluck.

```
<?php

function splitString( $pattern, $string ){

  $finalResult = $semiResult = $output = array();
  $cnt = 0;

  # first loop of patterns
  foreach( $pattern as $key => $value ){
    $cnt++;
    if( strpos( $string, $value ) !== false ){

      if( implode("",$output) != $string ){
          $output[] = $value;
          if( $cnt == count($pattern) ) $semiResult[]  = implode( ",", $output );
      }else{
        $semiResult[]  = implode( ",", $output );
        $output = array();
        $output[] = $value;
        if( implode("",$output) != $string ){
          $semiResult[]  = implode( ",", $output );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  # second loop of patterns 
  foreach( $semiResult as $key => $value ){
    $stackString = explode(",", $value);
    /* if value is not yet equal to given string loop the pattern again */
    if( str_replace(",", "", $value) != $string ){
      foreach( $pattern as $key => $value ){
        if( !strpos(' '.implode("", $stackString), $value) ){
          $stackString[] = $value;
        }
      }
      if( implode("", $stackString) == $string ) $finalResult[] = implode(",", $stackString); # if result equal to given string
    }else{
        $finalResult[] = $value; # if value is already equal to given string
    }
  }

  return $finalResult;
}

$pattern = array('in','do','mie','indo','mi','e', 'i');
$string = 'indomie';

var_dump( '<pre>',splitString( $pattern, $string ) );

?>
```